# Import neat causes error even though it is installed

Tags: python, modulenotfounderror

I've installed neat-python but when I try and import it in IDLE I get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
        import neat
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'neat'
```

I've been searching for a solution but cannot find any other than simply installing neat-python

```
Requirement already satisfied: neat-python in /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (0.92)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! (I am using macOS Catalina)

Comment: How did you install it? Are you executing the program using the Python installation to which you added the package?

Comment: Show us the output of `import sys; print(sys.path)` in the python shell.

Comment: @AMC I installed it through the terminal using "pip install neat-python". As far as I can tell I am using the Python installation that I added the package to, it shows the same path as my installation of pygame which is working just fine.

Comment: @JohnGordon ['', '/Users/seanhammell/Documents', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python37.zip', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload', '/Users/seanhammell/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages']

Comment: None of those are the `/opt/anaconda3/...` path, so that's the reason.  Are you using regular python, or are you using anaconda?

Comment: @JohnGordon As far as I can tell I'm using regular python. I followed the directions on https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/uninstall/ to uninstall any anaconda and redownload neat-python with no success.

Comment: @BigSeanyBoy _I followed the directions on docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/uninstall to uninstall any anaconda and redownload neat-python with no success._ You weren't able to uninstall Anaconda, or you weren't able to install neat-python?

Answer (score 0):

Check your python interpreter if you have multiple python versions installed.
In my case I had `Python 3.8` and `Python 3.9` installed on my computer and `NEAT` module was installed in `Python 3.9` and I was getting the error because I was using `Python 3.8`. So hopefully you have to change the interpreter of Python.